# Show that it is not a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Show that $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \ x= 0 \ \wedge \ y \geq 0 \ or \ x \geq 0 \ \wedge y=0  \}$ is not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

How would you proceed to solve this exercise?

$A$ is not open or discrete, so if $A$ is a manifold than it would be of dimension $1$.

Comment: What definition of manifold are you using? This set is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ so it can be endowed with a manifold structure.

Comment: Do you mean smooth submanifold of the plane?

Comment: Yes! I changed it thanks!

Comment: What is the tangent space at the origin?

Comment: Kajelad: It *is* a manifold, so your suggestion would not work. It is not a *smooth* submanifold of the plane.

Comment: @TedShifrin is it the entire space $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: But it must be a $1$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^2$, no?

Comment: yes exactly, so it can’t be a 1-dimensional subspace?